# async/await UI object winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

I am having some trouble understanding how to access UI object from my asynchronous method.

**UI Before**

```
 private void btnNavigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation n = new Navigation();
        n.Destination = cbQuickNav.Text;
        n.IEcheckState(n);
    }
```

**Async Method Before**

```
public async void IEcheckState(Navigation nav)
    {
        Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
        var ie = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("TS"));
        bool success = false;

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ie.GoTo("https://example.com");
            if (ie.ContainsText("Invalid login")) //Invalid login, please retry.
            {
                TSLogin(ie, nav);
            }
            else
            {
                quickNav(nav);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have read that async/await does not allow to pass an object by reference.  The navigate object is created on the main UI thread and is databound to controls on a form.  I'd like to be able to have the object persist through threads but I don't know how to accomplish this or how else to approach this problem.

**EDIT**

Pass by value is in fact working as Stephen advised below.  I found that my code was not setting the objects properties correctly...  My implentation was all wrong.  Instead of passing the object, I needed to just call a method on that object (such as n.IEcheckState()) and then access the properties with the "this" attribute.

**UI After**

```
 private void btnNavigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation n = new Navigation();
        n.Destination = cbQuickNav.Text;
        n.IEcheckState();
    }
```

**Async Method After**

```
public async Task IEcheckState()
    {
        Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
        var ie = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("TS"));
        bool success = false;

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ie.GoTo("https://example.com");
            if (ie.ContainsText("Invalid login")) //Invalid login, please retry.
            {
                TSLogin(ie);
            }
            else
            {
                quickNav(this);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read that async/await does not allow to pass an object by reference.

It does not allow you to use `ref`. When you pass a value of reference type (e.g., `IEcheckState`'s `nav` parameter), you are passing a reference by value. So you are sharing the same `nav` object between the caller and the callee.

Note the following best practices:

- Avoid `async void`. Use `async Task` unless the compiler *forces* you to change it to `async void`.
- Prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, [your blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) has been quite helpful. I am running .Net 4.0 and I seem to be unable to use Task.Run.  Do you know why that occurs?

Comment: @jmyns: Yes. I assume you're using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, and with that library you have to use `TaskEx.Run` instead of `Task.Run`.